# How to create an array of SKActions in Spritekit

Tags: ios, arrays, sprite-kit, skaction

I am trying to create an array of SKActions in Spritekit using objective-c so that two arrays execute in parallel. "rotation" is not an array which is fine with me, unless it is causing the issue which I doubt is the problem here. What I am expecting from this code is that actionMove and rotation will run in parallel and then it moves on to actionMove1 and actionMove2 and finishes the runAction. I am getting the following error in the last line of code shown below (added just the portion of the code needed).

Collection element of type 'SKAction *__strong [3]' is not an Objective-C object

```
SKAction * actionMove = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(actualX2, actualY2) duration:actualDuration];
SKAction * actionMove1 = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(actualX3, actualY3) duration:actualDuration];
SKAction * actionMove2 = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(actualX4, actualY4) duration:actualDuration];
int rotate = arc4random() % 5;
SKAction * rotation = [SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI/rotate duration:0.5];

SKAction * moveArray[] = {actionMove, actionMove1, actionMove2};

[game_piece1 runAction:[SKAction group:@[moveArray, rotation]]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want is a combination of group: and sequence: actions. Groups will run together and sequence will wait until the previous action is finished.

```
SKAction * actionMove = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(actualX2, actualY2) duration:actualDuration];
SKAction * actionMove1 = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(actualX3, actualY3) duration:actualDuration];
SKAction * actionMove2 = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(actualX4, actualY4) duration:actualDuration];
int rotate = arc4random() % 5;
SKAction * rotation = [SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI/rotate duration:0.5];

SKAction *firstStep = [SKAction group:@[actionMove, rotation]];
SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[firstStep, actionMove1, actionMove2]];

[game_piece1 runAction:sequence];
```

You might find this link helpful [Adding Actions to Nodes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/AddingActionstoSprites/AddingActionstoSprites.html) It does a good job of show different groups and sequences.

Hopefully that will give you the desired result.

**Edit**

If you are looking to run rotation while running move actions in oder it would look like this.

```
SKAction * actionMove = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(actualX2, actualY2) duration:actualDuration];
SKAction * actionMove1 = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(actualX3, actualY3) duration:actualDuration];
SKAction * actionMove2 = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(actualX4, actualY4) duration:actualDuration];
int rotate = arc4random() % 5;
SKAction * rotation = [SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI/rotate duration:0.5];

SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[actionMove, actionMove1, actionMove2]];
SKAction *group = [SKAction group:@[sequence, rotation]];

[game_piece1 runAction:group];
```

Comment: @SkylarLauren I apologize for the confusion. My plan is to actually have an array of three rotations as well.  So there will be two arrays, three actionMoves and three rotations running in parallel.  That is why I am using group:@ and not sequence:@

Comment: @Ino I updated the answer. You were very close then with your original code. The only issue is you don't pass an actually array of the movements, but instead create a sequence action to pass into the group.